# python-social-auth AuthCanceled exception

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-authentication, python-social-auth

I'm using python-social-auth in my Django application for authentication via Facebook.
But when a user tries to login, they have been redirected to the Facebook app page, and they click on the "Cancel" button, the following exception appears:

```
ERROR 2014-01-03 15:32:15,308 base :: Internal Server Error: /complete/facebook/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vera/virtualenv/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 114, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/vera/virtualenv/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 57, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vera/virtualenv/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/apps/django_app/utils.py", line 45, in wrapper
    return func(request, backend, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vera/virtualenv/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/apps/django_app/views.py", line 21, in complete
    redirect_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vera/virtualenv/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/actions.py", line 54, in do_complete
    *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vera/virtualenv/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/strategies/base.py", line 62, in complete
    return self.backend.auth_complete(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vera/virtualenv/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/backends/facebook.py", line 63, in auth_complete
    self.process_error(self.data)
  File "/home/vera/virtualenv/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/backends/facebook.py", line 56, in process_error
    super(FacebookOAuth2, self).process_error(data)
  File "/home/vera/virtualenv/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/backends/oauth.py", line 312, in process_error
    raise AuthCanceled(self, data.get('error_description', ''))
AuthCanceled: Authentication process canceled
```

Is the any way to catch it Django?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you can create a middleware and catch any exceptions, 
exception list: https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/social/exceptions.py
in this case your AuthCanceled Exception.

**middleware.py**

```
from social.apps.django_app.middleware import SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
from social import exceptions as social_exceptions

class SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware(SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if hasattr(social_exceptions, 'AuthCanceled'):
            return HttpResponse("I'm the Pony %s" % exception)
        else:
            raise exception
```

**settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
        .....
        'pat_to_middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
)
```

Comment: hasattr(social_exceptions, 'AuthCanceled')    returns true even if the exception is not AuthCanceled.  It catches all other errors even 404.

Comment: Caution, this will not work if INSTALLED_APPS includes 'debug_toolbar' as it wraps the middleware and prevents the exception from percolating through the process_exception functions

Comment: Yes, it's only an example.

Answer (score 45):

`python-social-auth` is a newer, derived version of `django-social-auth`.

AlexYar's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22059897/554894) can be slightly modified to work with `python-social-auth` by modify `settings.py` with following changes:

1. Add a middleware to handle the SocialAuthException

   ```
   MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += (
       'social.apps.django_app.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
   )
   ```
2. URL to redirect to, when an exception occurred

   ```
   SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_ERROR_URL = '/'
   ```
3. Note that you also need to set

   ```
   DEBUG = False
   ```

That's all or read http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/django.html#exceptions-middleware

Comment: finally an answer that works for the newer version! thanks :)

Comment: The key part for me was to set `DEBUG = False` This was driving me nuts, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Thanks Man..worked like charm. 
I am really thankful to stackoverflow. Its magic!

Answer (score 18):

This is slight modification of @Nicolas answer and this works for me.

**middleware.py**

```
from social.apps.django_app.middleware import SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware
from django.shortcuts import render
from social.exceptions import AuthCanceled

class SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware(SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if type(exception) == AuthCanceled:
            return render(request, "pysocial/authcancelled.html", {})
        else:
            pass
```

**settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += (
'myapp.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
)
```

Comment: Its `from social_auth.middleware import SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware`

Comment: @Chipmunk This answer is for python-social-auth , not for django-social-auth.

Comment: Its better to use different name for middleware than default class name SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware for clarity (which is matching the import)

Answer (score 5):

The 2018 answer:

1. Add `SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware` middleware to your config:

   ```
   MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
       ...
       'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
   ]
   ```
2. Set `SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_ERROR_URL` in your config:

   ```
   SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_ERROR_URL = '/login'
   ```

Now when you have `DEBUG = False`, your users will get redirected to your login page when they click cancel in social auth provider's page.

When `DEBUG = True` you will still see the error page in your browser during development.

Comment: As of 2020, this is the correct answer -- have verified with social-auth-app-django 4.0.0 and Django 3.0

Answer (score 2):

Just add in

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'social_auth.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
)

and something like

LOGIN_ERROR_URL = '/'

That's all
or read http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#exceptions-middleware

Comment: Note that this does not work for `python-social-auth`, the newer version. See @nattster's answer for the correct method.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about handling the exception do the following in your `settings.py`

`SOCIAL_AUTH_RAISE_EXCEPTIONS = False`

See this answer: [How to solve Authentication process canceled error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31958246/how-to-solve-authentication-process-canceled-error/37413652#37413652)

Answer (score 0):

This is a updated imports middleware using social_django

```
from social_django.middleware import SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware
from social_core import exceptions as social_exceptions
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

class FacebookAuthCanceledExceptionMiddleware(SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware):

    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if hasattr(social_exceptions, 'AuthCanceled'):
            return redirect('auth_login')
        else:
            raise exception
```