# How to solve faceook/linkedin Authentication process canceled error?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, authentication, cloud9

I have a project in AWS cloud9. When I tried to login via LinkedIn or Facebook, after pressing the "allow access" to my LinkedIn or Facebook account,  I get this error page:

Facebook:

[image: facebook]

LinkedIn:

[image: linkedin]

Traceback:

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://8011118167a14663bf26f276beae74fe.vfs.cloud9.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:80/complete/facebook/?redirect_state=s9F0XdwpzEpFx26DcClydCC2TI5gRICR&code=AQCHwhQV29jyqzxZ8_qtAQD6D_baKZvcdaMOL889co7q6N_rerhEvteJ3-1iE-vIhyX87qAHfCTN4XgoFF0IQT_MyWHsIf28ggfZt3IqUMXFODBsXaYY_PJJCvDRniv20gqMF9Pq1Lm2L1x-OFAOsqLsIboYZDrmG6ceFpADyzdKOXZRsy44uiXKhZIzht3VI45je8JbWowZJa-YUcRD1zY5OQnniW5ujq3IYe2l0z6nha6hq7Lk0lzLD5BR4I5O9sd7CdMxeRXX0NBmc9Qz4av2j2xsiHQq9zBASy03dSwENwQ2veIOhpQCMrIkkXwfNGQ&state=s9F0XdwpzEpFx26DcClydCC2TI5gRICR

Django Version: 1.8.4
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django_social_project',
 'django_social_app',
 'social.apps.django_app.default',
 'facebook_auth')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/apps/django_app/utils.py" in wrapper
  51.             return func(request, backend, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/apps/django_app/views.py" in complete
  28.                        redirect_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/actions.py" in do_complete
  43.         user = backend.complete(user=user, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/backends/base.py" in complete
  41.         return self.auth_complete(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/utils.py" in wrapper
  232.                 raise AuthCanceled(args[0])

Exception Type: AuthCanceled at /complete/facebook/
Exception Value: Authentication process canceled
```

I saw [How to solve Authentication process canceled error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31958246/how-to-solve-authentication-process-canceled-error) but It does not work.

I am using python Django v1.8.4.

settings.py :

```
import os
from config import *

SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_KEY = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_SECRET = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY =''
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_OAUTH2_KEY =''
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_OAUTH2_SECRET = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/home/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_URL = '/'

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 't+m0(7&y_%ek6&4r4z(4y3u31me(ld&zy*(()7fpkb2rn5ozm%'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_social_project',
    'django_social_app',
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
    'facebook_auth',
    )


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social.backends.linkedin.LinkedinOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'facebook_auth.backends.FacebookBackend',
    'facebook_auth.backends.FacebookJavascriptBackend',
    'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',

)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',

)


ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_social_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors':[
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.core.context_processors.debug',
                'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.core.context_processors.media',
                'django.core.context_processors.static',
                'django.core.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
                'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_social_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

urls.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

"""django_social_project URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Add an import:  from blog import urls as blog_urls
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^blog/', include(blog_urls))
"""
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls', namespace='auth')),
    url('', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
    url(r'^$', 'django_social_app.views.login'),
    url(r'^home/$', 'django_social_app.views.home'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'django_social_app.views.logout'),
    url(r'^personalDetsilsForm/$', 'django_social_app.views.personalDetsilsForm'),



]
```

view.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import logout as auth_logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.template.context import RequestContext


def login(request):
    #return render_to_response('login.html', context=RequestContext(request))
    print('this is print: ',request)
    return render(request, 'login.html')


@login_required(login_url='/')
def home(request):
    return render_to_response('home.html')


def logout(request):
    auth_logout(request)
    return redirect('/')
# Create your views here.

def personalDetsilsForm(request):
    return render_to_response('personalDetsilsForm.html')
```

login.html

```
<body style="background-color: white; text-align: center; padding-top:10%">
<img src="https://image.ibb.co/geWcEm/gowithhh.png" style="display:block;margin:auto;padding-bottom:5%;max-width:30%;">
{% if user and not user.is_anonymous %}
  <a>Hello, {{ user.get_full_name }}!</a>
  <br>
  <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
{% else %}
  <a href="{% url 'social:begin' backend='linkedin-oauth2' %}"><button class="button" style="background-color: #0077B5;"><span>Login with Linkedin</span></button></a><br><br>
  <a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}"><button class="button" style="background-color: #3b5998;"><span>Login with Facebook </span></button></a><br><br>
  <a href="/personalDetsilsForm"><button class="button" style="background-color: #f4511e;"><span>Tell us about yourself</span></button></a><br><br>
{% endif %}
</body>
```

Comment: Can you show us your code please?

Comment: I am not sure if this is your issue, but be sure to include the domain of your cloud 9 instance in your Facebook and Linkedin authorized domains.  You may be able to get away with a wildcard or omitting the left-most subdomain, that way you don't have to update your LinkedIn and Facebook apps every time you stop and start cloud 9.  I have successfully authenticated with Facebook via a Cloud 9 app using Rails, but I had to add the AWS domain.

Comment: @ubadub   
Thanks for your response. I edited the question and added my code. Do you have any solution?

Comment: @TomAranda my AWS is already a domain

Comment: @ubadub Thanks for your response. I edited the question and added my code. Do you have any solution?